# Can't login ubuntu after typing "chmod -R 744 /home"

Tags: ubuntu, authentication, chmod

Just a few days ago, I logged in my ubuntu PC as root, typed "chmod -R 744 /home", and rebooted my PC. Since then, I found that I couldn't log in my account due to permission issues. The only account I can log in is "guest". Can anyone help me so that I can log in ubuntu with my original account?

The version of my ubuntu is 12.04 LTS.

This is a huge problem to me, any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: I did this because last week I typed "chmod -R 777 /home" and I think having a permission of 777 is not safe. So I typed "chmod -R 744 /home" to make my system safer.

Comment: you should definitely avoid: 1)using root access 2)using -R option

Comment: how did you solved it? I have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Option 1:

- boot on a Live CD and mount your disk

Option 2:

- Reboot your machine in recovery mode (when booting press ESC or SHIFT many times) then follow this kind of tutorial:

http://naveenubuntu.blogspot.com/2012/05/recover-login-password-of-ubuntu-1204.html

When you get signed in as root, make your filesystem read-write (as shown in link above)

After option 1 or 2 is complete

```
chmod 755 /<mounted path>/home
chmod 755 /<mounted path>/home/<your user>
```

or

```
chmod 755 /home
chmod 755 /home/<your user>
```

755 will add back the 'x' flag that allows directory browsing.

Comment: are you sure about '-R' option?

Answer (score 0):

use live ubuntu CD to boot up from CD or USB stick, and fix the permissions on your `/home` directory back to normal